# Rubber: Cannot Find Bibliography Files When Building LaTeX Documents in a Separate Build Folder

Tags: bibliographies, windows, python, rubber

I recently installed [Rubber](https://gitlab.com/latex-rubber/rubber), a building system for LaTeX documents, using the command:

```bash
pip install latex-rubber
```

After installation, the Rubber Python scripts were placed in:

```
C:\Users\<userName>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Scripts\
```

I aim to build all LaTeX outputs into a separate `build` folder. To achieve this, I used the following command:

```bash
python C:\Users\<userName>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Scripts\rubber --pdf --into build main.tex
```

However, I encounter an issue where Rubber complains about not being able to find several `.bib` files with the error:

```
cannot find bibliography resource <fileName>.bib
```

I attempted an alternative approach by navigating to the `build` folder and executing:

```bash
python C:\Users\<userName>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Scripts\rubber --pdf  ..\main.tex
```

Unfortunately, I encountered the same error.

My project structure is as follows:

- `main.tex` is located in the root project directory.
- Some of the `.bib` files are located in the same directory as `main.tex`, and some are in other folders.
- I often use the `include` and `input` commands to modularize my document structure.
- I am using BibLaTex and biber on Windows using MiKTeX

I seek guidance on correctly configuring Rubber to find the `.bib` files when building the LaTeX document in a separate `build` directory.

Any advice or insights would be greatly appreciated!

**P.S.** The same issue has been reported [here](https://tex-talk.net/2011/12/building-documents-with-rubber/#comment-195).

**P.S.** From [here](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/rubber.1.html), Rubber has these "Module-specific directives," which are lines that start with a `%` sign, followed by any amount of whitespace, then the text "rubber:, "then whitespace, and finally the directive command name. Additional arguments, separated by spaces, can follow the directive command name. Some directives are specific to certain modules, which are plugins that extend Rubber's functionality. For example, the biblatex.path directive is part of the BibLaTeX module:

```
% rubber: biblatex.path <path>
```

and there is an example [here](https://gitlab.com/latex-rubber/rubber/-/tree/master/tests/biblatex-path-dir?ref_type=heads). But for some reason, I can't make it work!

Comment: For the sake of your sanity, don't use a build folder. Such things cause way more problems than they solve.